# Erro no Migrations EntityFramework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migrations

Erro ao realizar o Migrations.

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'SqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Meu App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
</startup>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MinhaStringDeConexao"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Adventure;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Eu chutaria erro na connectionString. Insira um ponto e virgula em  security=True;

Answer (score 0):

O seu `EntityFramework` não foi instalado corretamente, execute o seguinte comando na `Package Manage Console`.:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```